# How to show that a function has only one root in $(0,1)$?

Tags: calculus

The function $f(x)=x+\log x$ has only one root on $(0,\infty)$ which is in $(0,1)$.

Using the Intermediate value theorem: $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and $f(0)=0+\log(0)=-\infty<0$ and $f(1)=1+\log(1)=1>0$. So there exists an $x$ such $f(x)=0$.

But how to show that this $x$ is the only root?

Comment: What's the derivative of $f$?

Comment: $1+1/x$ but how to show the uniqueness/definiteness of the root?

Comment: What's the course you are taking now?

Comment: Is that derivative positive or negative? How does that affect the behavior of the function?

Comment: well for $f'(0)$ it is not defined and $f'(1)=2$ so I don't know if it's strictly monoton increasing. BTW I am taking Numerical Mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x+log(x)=log(e^xx)$ the question of finding the roots of the function $f(x)$ is the same question of finding the set of solutions of the equation $xe^x=1$. Let $g(x)=xe^x-1$ and $g(x)$ have two roots on $(0,1)$, say a and b. Since $g(a)=g(b)=0$, $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $g$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ we can apply rolles theorem and then there must be  $c\in(a,b)$ such that $g'(c)=0$ which requires the equation $e^c(c+1)=0$. But this equation is impossible for any $c\in(a,b)$ where $0<a,b<1$. So our assumption is false and $g$ has only one root in $(0,1)$ and so does $f$.

Comment: but $f$ is not continuous on the closed intervall $[0,1]$ so we can't use Rolle's theorem.

Comment: We are applying the Rolle's theorem to function $g$ which satisfy the conditions of the theorem, not to function $f$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1) $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)=-\infty .$

2) $f(1)=1$

3) $f(x)$ is increasing.

Can you conclude?

Comment: how do you show the monotonic increasing part? $f$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: derivative has always same sign

Comment: @blondy. the functions $x\mapsto x$ and $\log$ are increasing, hence their sum is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Note $f(1/e) = 1/e-1<0,$ $f(1) = 1>0.$ By the IVT, $f$ has a root in $(1/e,1).$ Also note $f'(x) = 1 + 1/x > 0.$ Thus $f$ is strictly increasing, and therefore the root just found is the unique root.